# SimpleDateFormat parsing and ambigious date formats

Tags: java, parsing, date

I'm trying to reject the parsing (through SimpleDateFormat::parse) of "18:00" from the date format HH. Is there an way to get this to happen without extra code? Does the date format accept $/regular expressions? I've enabled setLenient to false, and 18:00 still passes through the HH date format.

I realize I can make other comparisons to the string being parsed, but I'm looking for a way of doing this in the DateFormat string.

Comment: You can't do it with 'HH', but you can do it with 'hh' (I'm assuming you want people to only input hours 1 - 12 here...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SDF doesn't allow "rules". It just parses and formats dates according to a pattern, and not a regex-type pattern, either, so no regexes.

Answer (score 0):

1. SimpleDateFormat does perform a kind of validation - it will throw a ParseException if you're trying to parse a String which doesn't mean the specified format (although the Javadoc is crpytic about only throwing an exception if the start doesn't meet the format (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String))).
2. If the date format is just "HH", then the string "18:00" meets that format.  If the date format was "HH:MMM", (2-digit hour, followed by 3-letter month) then that should probably throw a ParseException.

If you're trying to validate like this, then I'd recommend using Regex, or even just using Java code.  I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve so I can't advise further I'm afraid.